# Equation involving functions

Tags: functions

I'm trying to solve numerically the following equation for $f(x)$ $$g(x)=f(x-x_0)+f(-x-x_0),$$ for a given $g(x)$ and $x_0$. I am using a least squares method that starts with an initial guess. What I find is that this equation is severely undetermined, meaning that there are many solutions that solve it. I would like to understand better what is going on because intuitively I was expecting the equation to have a unique solution for $f(x)$. The issue here is that I do not even know how the branch of mathematics that study equality between functions is called. Could anyone help me with reference books or ideas?

Comment: Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: Are there any condition to $g$ ?

Comment: It showed up in a high energy physics problem. $g$ is infinitely differentiable. I think that is the issue, my numerical algorithm is not guaranteeing continuity and I am getting all these discontinuous solutions. thank you @EDX.

Comment: @user191374 You welcome. Yes at least $C1$ seems to give interesting parity properties.